# d3.js: gradient fill is outline, how to make it solid?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a simple bar chart using d3.js with a linear gradient on two rect objects.  The gradient is there, but the gradient appears as an outline (two thin lines on the top and bottom of the rectangles).  I want solid fill with the gradient, not outline. After a lot of research, I still don't have the answer.

Here is the d3 javascript:

```
var dataArray = [23, 13];
var names = [ "Category1", "Category2" ];
var widths = [ "50", "700" ];

var svg = d3.select("svg.d3svg")
  .attr("height", "20%")
  .attr("width", "100%")

var bar = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(dataArray)
  .enter().append("g")

var gradient = svg
    .append("linearGradient")
    .attr("y1", "0%")
    .attr("y2", "100%")
    .attr("x1", "0%")
    .attr("x2", "100%")
    .attr("id", "gradient")
    .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")

gradient
    .append("stop")
    .attr('class', 'start')
    .attr("offset", "0%")
    .attr("stop-color", "red")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

gradient
    .append("stop")
    .attr('class', 'end')
    .attr("offset", "100%")
    .attr("stop-color", "green")
    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

var rect = bar.append('rect')
  .attr("height", "7")
  .attr("width", function(d, i) { return widths[i] })
  .attr("y", function(d, i) { return (i * 40) + 30 })
  .attr("x", "0")
  .attr("stroke", "url(#gradient)")

var text = bar.append('text')
  .attr("class", "text-svg")
  .text (function(d, i) { return names[i] })
  .attr("x", "0")
  .attr("y", function(d, i) { return (i * 40) + 50 });

var text = bar.append('text')
  .attr("class", "text-svg-caption")
  .text ("Text for this goes here")
  .attr("x", "135")
  .attr("y", "120");
```

So my question is how do I get a solid fill in the rectangles with a linear gradient?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `.attr("fill", "url(#gradient)")`: https://jsfiddle.net/7oy1pL6n/

Comment: Thanks very much.  That's the answer.